# How do I allow multiple roles to see a page when using a custom RoleProvider in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, roles

I have created my own Role Provider because I found the one that ASP.Net provides to be way too bulky in terms of tables in the database. I found implementing a custom RoleProvider to be quite easy.

My only problem is that right now I cannot have multiple roles for a page. I saw somewhere that at the top of your class you need to "anotate it" with some security code. This is what I have

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Admin")]
```

If I try to include multiple roles by using a comma separated list I get errors. If i try to specify multiple role keys then I also get errors. Do i Need to specify multiple PrinicipalPermissions by any chance?

I have very little experience with ASP.Net's role management. Can someone point me in the right direction or at some good literature.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

you can add the PrinicpalPermission attribute multiple times.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Admin")]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="AnotherRole")]
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, this is for multiple "OR" roles, not "AND".

Comment: Then can you refer on how to do 'AND'? I find the 'intersect' and 'union' methods quite confusing to read.

Answer (score -2):

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Admin,Another RoleName")]
```